# How to remove 1px margin from bootstrap's menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is bugging the heck out of me - I can't figure out how to override Bootstrap's styling to remove the 1px gap between the bottom of the menu button and the bottom of the navbar.  Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/32/

and here's a screen of what I'm trying to eliminate - the 1px below that anchor:

[image]

Any idea how this can be done?

```
code code
```

Comment: it is not about finding 1px margin. Make a better concept of positioning and sizing of all elements. You can not solve this simply just by adding line of code.

Comment: I didn't ask how to make bootstrap better, I asked how to modify its default styling.

Comment: Add a `style`, or create your own CSS classes and add the .css file _after_ the Bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: I did not actually notice the JSFiddle link because we generally post code in the question. But, I do see the problem now. Best of luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle seems to be broken, as it doesn't match the screen shot. So as a general answer, in a situation like this, one option is to set a negative bottom margin on the container. E.g.

```
{margin-bottom: -1px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

While this is a "band-aid" solution you can get the immediate results by doing a 1px negative margin to negate the 1px margin you cannot find that is causing your problem.